# SKProductsRequest returns invalid product identifiers in store version, works in TestFlight

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My iOS app has a single Subscription purchase. The in-app purchase flow works as expected in the TestFlight version of the app, however in the store version of the app the purchase flow does not work. The initial call using the SKProductsRequest method is returning the supplied product ID as invalid (this is not a guess, we have cloud-based logging and have captured the response to this request).

I have been over the various checklists of things to consider when receiving these invalid product identifiers (especially the points on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsresponse/1505985-invalidproductidentifiers) but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Going through the items in Apple's list explicitly:

- Agree to the latest Apple Developer Program License Agreement. > This is all done.
- Complete all the financial agreements as described in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking Overview. When you renew your developer membership, see if you need to make updates to your agreements. When your developer membership expires, your financial agreements expire as well. > The 'Paid Apps' agreement is active. Tax Forms are submitted for the United States and Australia. Banking is set up for Australia. Legal entity is in use.
- Your app uses an explicit App ID. > The app uses an explicit App ID.
- Clear the in-app purchases for sale in App Store Connect. See Set availability for in-app purchase. > The subscription product shows in App Store Connect with a status of 'Approved' (green tick).
- Modified in-app purchases are available to the App Store servers. > I'm not sure what this means?
- The product identifier specified in App Store Connect matches the identifier used by the SKProductsRequest object in your app. > This is correct, as proven by the purchases working in the TestFlight build.
- Upload the content of your product to App Store Connect. See Upload in-app purchase content to App Store Connect. > We are not hosting any content with our product (I don't believe this applies to Subscription products)

I've tried getting support from Apple, but it's like screaming into the void. Hoping that someone in StackOverflow land will have some hints about ways to solve this.

Comment: I'll put this as a comment because I don't know what is happening to you, but in local test and I guess in TestFlight, the request it not actually made if you have a mock App Store in your project. My In-App Purchases only work after I send a previous version with solo purpose of approval of the in-app purchases. Then another version to work in production. Have you make sure that all localization in your app is also present in the IAP?

Comment: Judging by the fact that everything works in `Testflight`, this is clearly something with banking, tax agreements, with approval in the AppStore. Go to the banking and tax settings and go straight into them and see if there is anything strange there - it happens that everything is fine, but you go in and one required field is empty. Any other in-app purchases? if they exist and work, then these are not taxes and a bank. Check that the subscription is all right there with localizations and prices. Well, how did you send it for review - you need to send IAP for review along with the new build.

Comment: And try to write to them here in support - https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/select App Setup and Distribution section - and there InApp Purchase and Subscription

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Very quickly, there's no mock App Store here, this is in the production verison of the app. @invzbl3, all great suggestions. I've been over every one of these forms and sections already, but will check again. There's a long & boring story about the app store submission process not letting me attach the IAPs with a new build, but they are now approved - I suspect this is the root cause of the issue (a flaw in the review system, inadvertantly triggered by a stressed out reviewer, though this is just a hunch). And I'm pursuing every support channel there is!

Comment: Did you encounter this after an App Store rejection? I had a case like this. As with you, my requests to the Review team to maybe cooperate and send some details on the error were completely ignored. After researching the topic, it seemed like the issue is pretty common. I remember seeing a Twitter post where someone filed a Code Level Support request on this subject and got a response like "we know, it's a bug, it's temporary, just wait it out". I ended up submitting after a week or two and my app got accepted.